# Sql Get distinct record from a table that has same foreign id and date record that is between the record it self and after 3 mintues

Tags: sql, entity-framework

considering i have these records 
table people (id ,name ,date)

- 1 mark 2017-10-1 05:00
- 1 mark 2017-10-1 05:01
- 1 mark 2017-10-1 05:02
- 1 mark 2017-10-1 05:03
- 2 joni 2017-10-1 05:00
- 2 joni 2017-10-1 05:01
- 2 joni 2017-10-1 05:02
- 2 joni  2017-10-1 05:03

the result of the query i want is :

- 1 mark 2017-10-1 05:03

  - 2 joni  2017-10-1 05:03

I want to get only two record (one for mark and one for joni ) since they have the same id and the difference of date is less or equal to  3 minutes 
how to  write this query

I have created a solution by declaring table inserting all the records inside it than loop in each record and check if there is any other record  that have same id with difference date of 3 min , so if exists  i delete that record.

but this solution is too long and takes too many resources (time) , i am looking for a better solution

Comment: I see more then 2 row pairs with the same id and the difference of date is less or equal to 3 minutes. Clarify your requiements.

Comment: @Serg that is right i want between them one record only (one for joni and one for mark)

Comment: Tag your dbms. Date arithmetic is sql product specific.

Comment: question i have, lets say you have till +6mins? now you have two 3min interval? which would be the basis? the last one? or the first one?

Answer (score 0):

This is an sql-server query. You may need to change `datediff` to an appropriate function of your DBMS. I assume you need the latest (as your desired output `2017-10-1 05:03` shows) row having a previous row within 3 minutes for a given id.

```
select id, name, dt 
from (
  select id, name, dt, row_number() over(partition by id order by dt desc) rn
  from (
    select id, name, dt
      , datediff(minute, lag(dt) over(partition by id order by dt), dt) diff
    from people 
  ) p
  where diff <= 3
) p
where rn=1;
```

Comment: it doesn't work 'lag' is not a recognized built-in function name.